# fun computational physics projects

Tags: computational-physics

I want to learn how to code in Java and am in need of some cool computational physics projects that would provide motivation to do so. I was wondering if you guys could list some medium-level computational physics projects (from any field) that you think would provide a well-rounded insight into programming.

Comment: Possibly a better home: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: It's a make-a-list, so it doesn't have a good home on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @dmckee MSE seems to be a good home for such questions